# Postgres limit param, default to infinite

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am passing a parameter into a Postgres query which allows the user to set the `LIMIT` of the result set. This parameter is optional and I would like to set the default `LIMIT` to infinite (no limit) but I'm not sure what to pass in this case. Would a limit of -1 be viewed as no limit?

Comment: From what I can understand "limit all" would return all rows

Answer (score 45, accepted):

[Quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-LIMIT)

> If the count expression evaluates to `NULL`, it is treated as `LIMIT ALL`, i.e., no limit

So just pass `NULL` for the limit and you'll get all rows.

Answer (score 4):

If a limit count is given, no more than that many rows will be returned (but possibly less, if the query itself yields less rows). LIMIT ALL is the same as omitting the LIMIT clause.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/queries-limit.html

Comment: My issue is that the parameter (`:limit`) passed in is an integer: `LIMIT :limit;` so I was hoping there was an integer representation of "infinite".

Comment: a_horse_with_no_name seems to have covered it :)