# How to apply a LIMIT in postgresql conditionally?

Tags: postgresql

I'd like to apply a LIMIT condition but only if the variable I am limiting by is populated. Otherwise no limit should be applied. The following syntax causes an error but provides an idea of what I'm trying to achieve

Example

```
SELECT 
    myTable."Id",
FROM reference.myTable myTable
CASE 
    WHEN @limit IS NOT NULL THEN LIMIT @limit
END;
```

Comment: If you use a null value, then limit is "unlimited", so you can use `limit @limit` assuming you mean that to be a parameter https://stackoverflow.com/a/39082815

Comment: I used your answer, it seemed the most fitting.

Answer (score 0):

Best you can do is probably this without dynamic SQL

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
ORDER BY id
LIMIT
    CASE WHEN :lim IS NULL THEN 99999999 ELSE :lim END;
```

Comment: Replace `99999999` with `NULL` and you will end up with no limit which I assume is what you are after.

Comment: Eliminate the `case` altogether. `Limit null` is the same al not specifying a limit at all. From the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-limit.html),  *LIMIT ALL is the same as omitting the LIMIT clause, as is LIMIT with a NULL argument.*

Comment: I did not know you could use a NULL as a limit at all. That's nice - I learned something today.